# "How to Format" box has bullet points that look like clickable drop-down arrows

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, user-interface

[image: WHY IS THIS IMAGE SO BIG?!?!?]

The triangle bullet points in the How to Format box look like clickable drop-down icons (at least to me). Should they be changed to round bullet points to avoid confusion?

Comment: This probably belongs on main Meta, not here.

Comment: @Rubio - why? It is fine to be here.

Comment: @Oded Only in that the scope of a fix for this should be everywhere, not just Puzzling. But if it's visible and actionable from site meta, so be it - much less pain for all that way :)